# How to output dependency walker to the console?

Tags: windows, dll, command-line, dependencies, dependency-walker

Fairly straightforward question, but I can't seem to find if this is an option in their command line help. Is there anyway to output the contents of the dependency walker directly to the console?

Yes, I'm aware that you can specify it to output to a file and then I can parse the file, however that takes a bunch of time that I would rather avoid.

I'm not necessarily worried about how "ugly" it looks in the console. I can programmatically search what I want from the output pretty quickly, just need to know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance if you can offer any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) is a modern replacement for dependency walker. It contains both a GUI tool and a console app (dependencies.exe), which dumps as you require. It supports the following options:

```
Dependencies.exe : command line tool for dumping dependencies and various utilities.
Usage : Dependencies.exe [OPTIONS] FILE

Options :
  -h -help : display this help
  -json : activate json output.
  -apisets : dump the system's ApiSet schema (api set dll -> host dll)
  -knowndll : dump all the system's known dlls (x86 and x64)
  -manifest : dump FILE embedded manifest, if it exists.
  -sxsentries : dump all of FILE's sxs dependencies.
  -imports : dump FILE imports
  -exports : dump  FILE exports
  -modules : dump FILE resolved modules
  -chain : dump FILE whole dependency chain
```

Comment: I ended up going with dumpbin to handle the requirements I needed, but I will definitely look into this later and evaluate it for my team. Being able to dump the whole dependency chain may actually be extremely useful for the application I wrote. Thanks a lot for this!